# Setting Time Labels on RangeBar Chart

Tags: asp.net, charts

I have a RangeBar chart that will show different schedules and how they overlap. I can't seem to get AxisY (which is really AxisX, but they switch when you use a RangeBar for some reason) to display the hour. It displays a gridline for every hour, but the label is the date, which is not helpful at all.

I tried

```
asChart.ChartAreas["ChartArea1"].AxisY.CustomLabels.Add(0, DateTimeIntervalType.Hours, string.Format("{0:H}"));
```

but I get the error: `Index (zero based) must be greater than or equal to zero and less than the size of the argument list.`

Can somebody point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay. I'm dumb.

```
asChart.ChartAreas["ChartArea1"].AxisY.LabelStyle.Format = "{HH:mm}";
```